# How does convergence of $\frac{W_{t}+ct}{t}, W_{t}$ is Brownian motion, imply $W_{t}+ct$ diverges?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

How does convergence of $\frac{W_{t}+ct}{t}, W_{t}$ is Brownian motion, imply $W_{t}+ct$ diverges (taking $c>0$)?

Clearly, $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{W_{t}+ct}{t} =\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{W_{t}}{t}+c =c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $W_t+ct$ converges then $\frac {W_t+ct} t \to 0$. But this limit is $c >0$.

Comment: That makes intuitive sense - perhaps this was actually then a question best suited for real analysis.